# Upload binary does not show on Itunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app to the apple store, but itunes connect looks to be bugged.

I already uploaded the binary 3 times with success, and so far, it didn't show up on the "Build" section. I'm using Xcode 6.2 and Application Loader 3.0. So I met all requirements.

The "+" button does not show on the build section also.

Looking for solutions I found some complaints even from 2014 but no perfect solution that will work for everyone.

Have you any ideal about what can I do?

My last binary upload was about 8 hours ago and nothing happened yet.

Status is as "Prepare for Submission".

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I found all my uploaded binaries in another App.

This happened because I was using a wildcard provisioning profile. This caused the file not to be shown on the right app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the some problem, and waited for more than 8 hours without any result. Then I saw a new (tax-agreement) *contract that I had not signed*. I signed it, waited for a few more minutes, and then the plus-sign showed up!